# I have a hard time understanding some of the Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I'm having a hard time understanding the two lines of the code in codecademy.

```
require 'prime'

def first_n_primes(n)
  "n must be an integer" unless n.is_a? Integer
  "n must be greater than 0" if n <= 0
  prime = Prime.instance
  prime.first n
end

first_n_primes(10)
```

Can you please explain what `Prime.instance` means and what `prime.first n` is?

Comment: `Prime` is a class from ruby stdlib: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prime numbers are a universal notion, and you don't need to think about creating different instances of the enumerator/set of primes each time you use it your code. (Ideally,) it should be comparable to modules/methods on which you call singleton methods like:

```
Math.sin(0)
```

instead of the wrong form:

```
Math.new.sin(0)
```

However, `Prime` class was (incorrectly) designed to be used like in the latter form above:

```
Prime.new.each(30)
```

with there being only a single instance of the prime enumerator (i.e., `Prime` being a singleton class). So for historical reason, this usage is kept (up to Ruby 2.2), but it was later noticed that, since it is a singleton, it should be encouraged to replace `new` by `instance`:

```
Prime.instance.each(30)
```

as with classes that include the `Singleton` module do.

Regarding your `first n`, it takes the first `n` elements from the enumerator.

Comment: In Ruby 2.3, `Prime` includes `Singleton` and doesn't allow `Prime.new` any more.

Answer (score 3):

Prime is a Ruby class. By calling `prime = Prime.instance`, you are instantiating an object called `prime` of the `Prime` class, which is basically the set of all prime numbers. This object has the public methods of the class `Prime` including `#first` which when presented an argument `(n)`, will return an array of the first n prime numbers.